# split values to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like :

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3
 1 | 1,2  | 2,5  | 6,3
 2 | 3,5,6|1,2,3 |9,8,7
```

i want output like this :

```
id | newCol1 | newCol2 | newCol3
 1 |  1      |    2    |   6
 1 |  2      |    5    |   3
 2 |  3      |    1    |   9
 2 |  5      |    2    |   8
 2 |  6      |    3    |   7
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add what you have tried so far and where you are getting stuck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: Here is a [T-SQL solution fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/456565/1) if anyone feels like converting it to MySql...

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use a `substring_index()` and a bunch of `union all`s:

```
select id,
       substring_index(col1, ',', 1) as newcol1,
       substring_index(col2, ',', 1) as newcol2,
       substring_index(col3, ',', 1) as newcol3
from t
union all
select id,
       substring_index(substring_index(col1, ',', 2), ',', -1) as newcol1,
       substring_index(substring_index(col2, ',', 2), ',', -1) as newcol2,
       substring_index(substring_index(col3, ',', 2), ',', -1) as newcol3
from t
where col1 like '%,%'
union all
select id,
       substring_index(substring_index(col1, ',', 3), ',', -1) as newcol1,
       substring_index(substring_index(col2, ',', 3), ',', -1) as newcol2,
       substring_index(substring_index(col3, ',', 3), ',', -1) as newcol3
from t
where col1 like '%,%,%'
```

You can keep adding more subqueries up the the longest list that you have.